# Exclude tokens from Identifier lexical rule

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have Identifier lexical rule:

```
Identifier
:   ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' ) ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9' )*
;
```

LogicalOr and LogicalAnd rules:

```
LogicalOr       :   '| ' | '||' | OR;
LogicalAnd      :   '&' | '&&' | AND;
fragment Or : '[Oo][Rr]';
fragment And : '[Aa][Nn][Dd]';
```

strings "and" and "or" are recognized as identifiers, instead of logicalAnd and logicalOr. Could someone help me to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential issues at play. First and foremost, ANTLR 3 does not support the character class syntax introduced by ANTLR 4. Your `Or` fragment literally matches the input `[Oo][Rr]`; it does not match `OR`, `or`, or `oR`. The same applies to your `And` fragment. You need to write the rule like this instead:

```
fragment
Or
  : ('O' | 'o') ('R' | 'r')
  ;
```

If this does not resolve your issue, then you need to make sure your `LogicalOr` and `LogicalAnd` rules are positioned before the `Identifier` rule in the grammar. The rule which appears first will determine what token type is assigned for this input sequence.

Comment: Thanks so much! I moved Identifier rule after LogicalOr and LogicalAnd rules. The problem is solved.

Comment: @SLX: if this answer solved your problem then please accept it (click the big check mark below the vote counter). If you find it especially useful then also upvote the answer by clicking the up arrow above the vote counter.